# Facebook share thumbnail not showing until refreshed

Tags: posts, facebook

When I FB Share any post only thing that appears is text and no thumbnail like this:

[image]

I need to close this window and retry sharing few times (or just F5 few times) and eventually thumbnail will appear.

Im using "Tweet, Like, Google +1 and Share" plugin but I also tried another plugins like Jetpack Share etc. with same result so I don't think problem is plugin related.

Thumbnails are included like this:

```
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

                    the_post_thumbnail('bigthumb', array('class' => 'singlethumb'));

                    }
```

Also tried to change thumbnail size to smaller or including 2 thumbnail sizes (just for tests) with same result.

Is this just how FB Share works with WP or what?

Comment: I am sure it must be something to do with cache or your specific PC or may be your connection. If FB is showing image after couple of refresh then there should not be any issue with WordPress. Try it on your friends PC on different internet connection.

Comment: Thx I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Google "facebook linter". Choose the first search result which will be from official facebook website. Go there, enter your url, hit submit (or similar button for submission). Now come back to facebook profile, and post the url as an update. You will get the thumbnail.

Comment: Purpose of having share buttons below my post content is not only me sharing but also users/readers. I can't write them "facebook linter instruction". When reader tries to share post and don't see thumbnail, I don't think he will try to refresh.

Comment: try doing it once while posting your link. Once it will come up in your posted link, it should start coming for other people too who share your link/post. They won't need to follow same process again. Only the original link poster needs to do so, that too just for the first time.